# как сделать скриншот используя встроенные библиотеки? это возможно?

Tags: python, python-3.x

можно ли сделать скрин используя встроенные библиотеки python?
win 10

Comment: Да, это возможно. Но для разных операционных систем реализация будет разной.

Comment: @insolor а как сделать для виндовс 10?

Comment: С помощью библиотеки ctypes обращаетесь к функциям winapi, получаете контекст экрана, копируете из него все в контекст в памяти, сохраняете в файл в bmp. Примерно как в этом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59352906/4752653 только там используется устанавливаемый модуль pywin32 (и PIL для конвертации в png), но по идее можно переписать все на ctypes, и сохранять в bmp, тогда PIL не нужен будет.